# how to import excel file to sqlite database and show the database in table view in android?

Tags: android, excel, sqlite, tableview

I have been searched for many question about **import excel file to sqlite database**, but still do not understand how to create the code, also want to **show the database in android with table view after imported the excel file**.. anyone help please? thanks before

Answer (score 0):

There is no method available to import excel file to SQL or sqlite db.